# How to programmatically export any MTLTexture to KTX in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, metal

#### Detail

We can export the raw texture data including other layers or slices in KTX format after we capture the frame by [the frame capture.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/debugging_tools)

[image]

After that, we can import by using [MTKTextureLoader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtktextureloader).

```swift
let texture = try! await loader.newTexture(URL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "texture", withExtension: "ktx")!)
```

#### Goal

But how to programmatically export the MTLTexture to KTX format in Swift?

Comment: I am pretty sure you would have to write your own exporter for this.

Comment: Or you can just use `toktx` or `libktx` from https://github.com/KhronosGroup/KTX-Software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `ImageIO` whether ImageIO supports the format you want to export to:

Call `CGImageDestinationCopyTypeIdentifiers()` from `ImageIO` module to get a list of all the UTI that the `CGImageDestination` supports.

For example, these are the types ImageIO supports on my machine:

```
(
    "public.jpeg",
    "public.png",
    "com.compuserve.gif",
    "public.tiff",
    "public.jpeg-2000",
    "com.apple.atx",
    "org.khronos.ktx",
    "org.khronos.ktx2",
    "org.khronos.astc",
    "com.microsoft.dds",
    "public.heic",
    "public.heics",
    "com.microsoft.ico",
    "com.microsoft.bmp",
    "com.apple.icns",
    "com.adobe.photoshop-image",
    "com.adobe.pdf",
    "com.truevision.tga-image",
    "com.ilm.openexr-image",
    "public.pbm",
    "public.pvr"
)
```

Then, use `CGImage` to output it:

```
let texture: MTLTexture = ... // input texture
let ciContext = CIContext(mtlDevice: texture.device)
let ciImage = CIImage(mtlTexture: texture, options: nil) // you might need to add `.oriented(.downMirrored)` here
let colorspace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)
let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, from: .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: texture.width, height: texture.height)), format: .RGBA8, colorSpace: colorspace)!

let uniformType: UTType = ... // uniform type from CGImageDestinationCopyTypeIdentifiers
let outputURL: URL = ... // the url

try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: outputURL.deletingLastPathComponent(), withIntermediateDirectories: true) // you might needs this to create intermediate directories

let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(outputURL as CFURL, uniformType.identifier as CFString, 1, nil)!
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, cgImage, nil)
let imageOutputSuccessfully = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
```

Comment: It can export but the depth is not match the original. (MTLTexture RGB from depth 8 to depth 16). Do I need to add some thing to solve this?

Comment: I haven't tried exporting depth formats. Definitely most of these output types won't support a 32 bit formats. I think OpenEXR should support something like this, ktx maybe also. Try specifying `kCIFormatRf`. for `MTLPixelFormatDepth32Float` textures.